# Send payload data with POST/PUT/PATCH requests to Sentry.io

Tags: angular, sentry

I'm trying to add the payload data to the breadcrumbs sent to Sentry.io.

It just looks like this.

[image]

I found out how to add the response.

```
const sentryConfig: BrowserOptions = {
  beforeBreadcrumb: (breadcrumb, hint) => {
    if (breadcrumb.category === 'xhr') {
      // hint.xhr is a whole XHR object that you can use to modify breadcrumb
      breadcrumb.data = (hint.xhr as XMLHttpRequest).response;
    }

    return breadcrumb;
  }
};
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to add the payload. `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't have this info.

Comment: The close-reason is illegitimate. Ask for clarification first if you don't understand the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to get the body (payload data) from your xhr this way:

```
beforeBreadcrumb: (breadcrumb, hint) => {
 if (breadcrumb.category === 'xhr') {
   const data = {
     requestBody: hint.xhr.__sentry_xhr__.body,
     response: hint.xhr.response,
     responseUrl: hint.xhr.responseURL
   }
   return { ...breadcrumb, data }
 }
 return breadcrumb
}
```

This is the [PR](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/pull/2904/files) where it was added.

Comment: the sentry API slightly changed:   
requestBody: hint.xhr.__sentry_xhr_v2__.body

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to get the payload from the xhr request. I would just `console.log()` with the payload wherever you have it when creating the xhr request. It will not be part of the same breadcrumb but you will see it in Sentry.

Comment: Manually sending this information does seem to be the only way, At least for now. Wonder why this isn't requested more as it seems rather important when trying to figure out what went wrong

Comment: @Snæbjørn requested from whom? As you can see there is no way to extract this from a XHR request object.

Comment: Requested as a feature in the Sentry `beforeBreadcrumb` callback

Comment: There is no way to implement this feature.